# How do I use GlobalStyles from styled components in next?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, styled-components

I'm starting now to learn next. I'm kind of lost on how to apply the createGlobalStyle feature of the sytled components in the framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go to [Vercel github](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-styled-components) and install:

```js
npx create-next-app --example with-styled-components with-styled-components-app
# or
yarn create next-app --example with-styled-components with-styled-components-app
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom app, by creating a _app.js file in pages directory

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components'

const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  body {
    color: ${props => (props.whiteColor ? 'white' : 'black')};
  }
`

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <><GlobalStyle whiteColor /><Component {...pageProps} /></>
}

export default MyApp
```

Check https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app

Comment: Thanks! I use import. `import { GlobalStyles } from '../../GlobalStyles'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <>
      <GlobalStyles />
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  )
}

export default MyApp`

Comment: There's a problem, whenever I refresh the page it goes back to global styles. The styles I apply by styled components don't override global styles.

Comment: Take a look on https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-styled-components/pages/_document.js probably is needed for your use because rehydration

Comment: Thanks! Is working now.

Comment: Now the GlobalStyles is duplicated.